# How to stop or break (or raise error) execution of a script in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

In Vertica, I would like to stop running the script if certain condition meets. For example, if my script finds that a table has non-zero rows, then the rest of the script should no longer run (that is, the script should quit) and raise some sort of error message (e.g., RAISEERROR in SQL SERVER).

I can only think of wrapping the rest of the script with `CASE WHEN`, like this:

```
CASE
WHEN (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            my_table ) <= 0 THEN
    'the rest OF the script here'
ELSE
    'ALERT: Make sure there is nothing left in my_table'
END
```

but I'm wondering if there is an alternative (more standard) approach in Vertica. Thank in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you specifically talking about `vsql` scripts? What you have won't work, if I understand when you are trying to do properly. Could you give an example of the script?  Also know that Vertica is not an OLTP database, it kind f looks like you are planning to do row by row processing. If so, my suggestion is... don't.

Comment: @woot, Thank you for the reply. I am using vertica sql (vsql?) script and it is shared here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7db5/1197]. The plan is to detect, as part of the automated/scheduled process, if there is any unmapped/new `campaign_group_name` and if so, do not proceed to the next steps. I am not trying to process row by row. Just wanted to see if `campaign_group_names_to_map` table has any row, do not proceed beyond Step4 in the fiddle above. Thank you for any advice that you can provide!

Comment: Ok so a couple things about Vertica. It doesn't actually have stored procedures (although it does have UDX but that needs to be installed at the server level and doesn't really let you do things like run queries and do flow control like that). The utility to run sql in a script is `vsql`. It has limited functionality with regards to what you are trying to do. There is no flow control in `vsql`. I would recommend either using a scripting language like python or write shell scripts wrapping the `vsql`  calls. There is a way to maybe force an error condition, it's kind of a vsql hack though.

Comment: @woot, Thank you for the follow-up answer! I saw an example forcing an error somewhere on the internet. I think I'll try that approach for now. If I ever come up with a better alternative, I'll share with the StackOverflow community. :) Have a good weekend!

Comment: Yeah, basically enable stop on error, then force a divide by zero error or something similar I think.  That's the hack I was talking about.

Comment: @woot, Yes. That's what I saw others suggested, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Vertica does not have a control flow facility so control flow has to be handled outside of the query and vsql

1. Execute a vsql query to do something
2. Execute a vsql query to detect
   if something was done
3. If success then execute next vsql query to do
   something ...etc

Using Linux Bash you could try something like

```
vsql -d YourDb -h YourHost -f Your.sql > 2&1
exit_code = "$?"

if [ "$exit_code" -ge "1" ] then;
  exit(1)
fi
```

The 2&1 redirects stderr to stdout.

- stderr 1 = some form of error occurred in the script
- stderr 2 = some
  form of connection termination occurred when running the script

Another approach would be to have a query return a value to detect if a previous script had the desired result

```
result_code = $(vsql .....etc)

if [ "$result_code" -eq "your trigger value" ] then;
   exit(1)
fi
```

To signal a condition you can either have a query return a single scalar value or you can do use something similar to your original query with the > 2&1

```
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a.cnt = 0
            THEN 1/0 -- Forces an error that will be picked up by >2&1
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM
            my_table) AS a;
```

The approach I would take would be to set up a bash script to loop a manifest file containing the names of the scripts I want to execute in the order I want to execute them.
I would have the bash script maintain a count of the files execute echoing them out to a deployment log.

I could always do a COPY FROM of the deployment log into a Vertica table at the end of the deployment so I can tell if the number deployed = the number that should have been deployed.  It would also identify the point at which the deployment stopped so you know what to rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Vertica 7.2 You can use the `THROW_ERROR ( msg )` [function](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Error-handling/THROW_ERROR.htm).

Answer (score -1):

If anyone wants to know how to force error in Vertica using `CASE WHEN`, this is one way:

```
SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a.cnt = 0
            THEN 'do something'
            ELSE 'do other thing'
        END
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM
            my_table) AS a;
```

Comment: This doesn't throw an error if the table has 0 rows.